# Problemas ao definir width em div, sistema de abas

Tags: jquery, html, css

Galera criei um sistema de abas simples, usando css,html e jquey. Porém estou tendo um problema ao definir o `width` das abas.

Para ficar mais fácil de explicar irei postar o código aqui:

```js
function corrige_altura() {
    $('.tabs-container').css({
      height: $('.tabs:checked + label + div').height() + 80  
  });

}

$(function(){
    corrige_altura();
});
```

```css
/* Container das ABAS */
.tabs-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
/* ABAS */
input.tabs {
    display: none;
}
input.tabs + label + div {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
}
input.tabs + label + div {
    z-index: -1;
}
input.tabs:checked + label + div {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Labels */
input.tabs + label {
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    background: #484848;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
input.tabs + label:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #fff;
}
input.tabs:checked + label {
    color: #000;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%">
 <td width="50px" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>
    
    <div class="tabs-container">

    <!-- ABA 1 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="tabs" id="tab1" checked>
    <label for="tab1">aba1</label>
    <div>

       asdasdasd


    </div>

    <!-- ABA 2 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="tabs" id="tab2" >
    <label for="tab2">aba2</label>
    <div>

      sadsad

    </div>

</div>
    
    
  </td>
 <td width="50px" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">&nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

Bom notem que ao definir:

```
input.tabs + label + div {width: 100%;}
```

A abas fica sobrepondo a tabela onde ela esta, quero que ela fica em 100% da tela. Porém respeitando a tabela onde ela esta.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, isso é devido ao `padding`

altere o trecho para

```
    input.tabs + label + div {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
}
```

assim mantendo o padding height e tirando apenas o do width

Visualize no

### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd31vLpb/1/)

Observações

### Margin

A propriedade margin simplesmente adiciona uma margem ao seu elemento. Você pode utilizar qualquer medida Css (px, pt, em, %...) como tamanho da propriedade margin, além disso você pode atribuir valores negativos, mas tenha cuidado com eles.

### Padding

O padding tem um funcionamento muito similar ao do margin, porém ao invés de dar uma espaçamento externo, ele da um interno.

> Observação extraída de [devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-usar-as-propriedades-margin-e-padding-css/24409)

Comment: tentei aqui, porém o erro ainda continua. segue link https://jsfiddle.net/nd31vLpb/

Comment: @HugoBorges olha o link que postei junto com a resposta

Comment: perfeito funcionou 100% muito brigado

Comment: amigo notei so uma coisa, com isso eu perdi uma margem de 10px que tinha dentro da aba, tem como colocar ela novamente?

Comment: Margin na lateral? Olha a observação que adicionei a resposta para que possa entender melhor a diferença entre as propriedades `margin` e `padding` @HugoBorges

Comment: não margem interna, mas ja resolvi, criei uma nova div e atribui uma margem. Segue o link: https://jsfiddle.net/nd31vLpb/2/

Comment: @HugoBorges Beleza. Obs: margin interna no css é conhecida como `padding`

Comment: ok, muito obrigado, sem sua ajuda não teria resolvido. vlw e fica com Deus